# Unable to build android studio project cannot access zzbcc class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcc not found

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, google-maps-markers

Everything was fine building but recently in on week time, now the project is not building,

cannot access zzbcc class file error is related to maps maybe
as it occurs on Add marker method for google map code i have used in my project

This is my current gradle build file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}}


dependencies {


/*For Facebook Sign in*/
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
//fort lib
compile project(':FORTSDKv1.4')
compile project(':likebutton')
compile project(':infiniteviewpager')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.0.0'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
compile 'com.github.florent37:arclayout:1.0.1'
compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.2.1'
compile 'com.yayandroid:ParallaxRecyclerView:1.1'
compile 'com.github.scottyab:showhidepasswordedittext:0.8'
compile 'com.txusballesteros:bubbles:1.2.1'
compile 'com.victor:lib:1.0.1'
compile 'com.shamanland:fonticon:0.1.8'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46'
compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
compile 'com.vinaygaba:creditcardview:1.0.3'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.github.damson:Bright:v1.1.0-release'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
compile 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
// OneSignal SDK
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.1,3.99.99)'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
//compile 'com.adjust.sdk:adjust-android-criteo:4.2.3'
compile 'com.adjust.sdk:adjust-android:4.11.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.2.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Clean builds successfull but cannot run app or generate signed apk, 
I have seen multiple simmilar questions they point towards dependency issue but in this case firebase and google play services both are same.

---

**Resolved**
By making firebase and google play service dependencies same and also using latest stable version for both

Comment: Try to clear Android studio cache and build. File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: Nope that doesn't help, still same issue @vsvankhede

Answer (score 0):

Update to latest google play version and firebase in gradle dependencies

I just had to change dependency version in gradle to latest and all build issue were resolved.
thanks.